# LitElement remove item from list

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, lit-element

When the page first loads, the delete buttons generated by the code below work as expected. However, if you alter the text in one of the `<textarea>` elements, the delete button no longer works correctly. How can I fix this?

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      list: { type: Array },
    };
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.list = [
      { id: "1", text: "hello" },
      { id: "2", text: "hi" },
      { id: "3", text: "cool" },
    ];
  }
  render() {
    return html`${this.list.map(item =>
        html`<textarea>${item.text}</textarea><button id="${item.id}" @click="${this.delete}">X</button>`
    )}`;
  }
  delete(event) {
    const id = event.target.id;
    this.list = this.list.filter(item => item.id !== id);
  }
}
customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
```

Comment: Hm. The odd thing is that the list is correct but displays incorrectly. Look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-list-element?file=my-element.js   Edit 'hi' to 'hi there', tab out, then delete. The list in the console is correct, the display is not.

Comment: Actually displayed list is updated and the content of textarea is also updated (innerHtml shows updated content if you change the list.text), but the content of edited textarea is not updated visually. This same error occurs also with <input type=text>-element. It’s like the browser remembers which input-box is edited and keeps it’s content intact visually after the update.

Comment: Try using [the `repeat` directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#repeating-templates-with-the-repeat-directive).

Comment: I agree with @grohjy, the list is actually updated and the elements rendered again, you can see if you inspect, it's just a metter that the browser keeps visually the first two textareas after you remove one. Another proof that is some sort of "cache" is the fact that after re-render you still see what you typed, but since you are not updating `this.list` everytime it should render with the initial values (and it does if you inspect).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact cause, but I think it has to do with the way lit-html decides which DOM elements to remove when rendering a list with fewer items than the previous render. The solution is to use the [`repeat` directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#repeating-templates-with-the-repeat-directive). It takes as its second argument a function that helps lit-html identify which DOM elements correspond to which items in the array:

```
import { repeat } from 'lit-html/directives/repeat.js'

// ...
render(){
  return html`
    ${repeat(this.list, item => item.id,
      item => html`<textarea>${item.text}</textarea><button id="${item.id}" @click="${this.delete}">X</button><br>`
    )}
  `;
}
```